# unable to access the cloud Firestore in Project A from cloud function in Project B - '403 Missing or insufficient permissions'

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

Cloud Firestore in Project A,
Cloud Functions in Project B

I'm able to access the cloud Firestore of 'Project A' from cloud shell of 'Project B' but not through cloud functions of 'Project B'. Here's the code of the cloud function uses

```
from google.cloud import firestore 
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

def function_a(request):

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'projectId': 'project-a',
    })
db = firestore.client()
try:
    doc_ref=db.collection('COLLECTION_SAMPLE').document('documentA').set({"foo":"bar"})
except Exception as e:
    print("error::", e)
    
return "success"
```

Cloud functions in Project B use the service account `project-b@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
the service account has roles (`Cloud Datastore User`, `Cloud Functions Developer`, `Editor`) in Project B and has the role of (`Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin`) in project A.

I encounter `403 Missing or insufficient permissions`.

Comment: Hi, Sridhar! Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your code as

```js
    db = firestore.Client(project='project-a')
```

2. Find the service account of your Cloud Function. As you mentioned, usually it should be `project-b@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. Copy the service account ID.
3. In the GCP console of project `project-a` > IAM & Admin > IAM, add the service account mentioned in step 2 as its member and grant it the roles needed, i.e. Cloud Datastore Viewer.